# Custom User-Group: Giving access to users component administration

Tags: administrator, acl, user-groups, permissions, global-configuration

I created a user group with access to the users component. In Global Config, all access options are marked to "Allow":

[image: com_users permissions]

However, in admin, this menu item does not show up:

[image: admin menu]

This is the advanceed permissions report for this group:

[image]

Other components are working OK, so is there anything special to do with this component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **can not** reproduce this on a **Joomla! 3.7.2.**

The steps below are what I did. Can you follow them and report back if this works for you?

1. Created the **Custom User-group**, it is a child of the **Public**  - I called it "users-managers".
2. Gave full Permissions = set everything to **Allowed** for the new user-group, through the Options of the users component.
3. Gave **Special** **Viewing Access Levels** for the new group.
4. Gave only **Administrator Login** permissions from the **Global Configuration** for the new Group.
5. Create a new user and assign him to the new group (only to that group) - use another browser to login and test.
   This user should only see the following menu items on the admin menu:

> System(->Control Panel only) | Users (and all children items) | Help (if it's
>   enabled)

If the above won't produce the expected result - then see if there is any 3rd party ACL extension installed and also if there is any custom admin menu.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I did exactly the same thing, except step 3, which I don't know where it is / how to do it.

Comment: @NunoNogueira step 3 is the Access Levels that you can find under the Users item of admin menu - or Viewing Access Levels found on the left sidebar when you are already in the com_users. Click the **Special** level and checkmark your new user-group. This is strange though that you were able to see the admin menu and other elements in the backend without giving viewing access to your user-group

Comment: Ok, I got the special viewing access level. But it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @NunoNogueira Is it fresh Joomla installation? any chance that you have installed other extensions that are related to ACL? And can you post/share screenshots of what you are seeing?

Comment: No, it's an old installation. In my edited question above you may see the advanced permissions report for this group.

Comment: @NunoNogueira - is it J3.7.2? The screenshot also says that the report is for the user group Administrator. So are you sure you are editing and checking for your custom user-group?

Comment: Yes, 3.7.2. I call this user group Administrador.

Comment: @NunoNogueira - 3rd party ACL extensions? or likely a custom admin menu? And are you still able to see the Content menu item? What happens if you click on the Content->Articles?

Comment: I'm not using any other extension to manage ACL. Content and Component menus are working fine. But no Users menu item.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've figured out what was causing the problem. The user I tested to check this user group was also part of another user group with conflicting permissions.... Sorry about that.

Comment: @NunoNogueira - Having the content and component menus showing there means that you haven't done exactly what I described above. This isn't necessary though for getting the desired result but just mention it as it may be indication that you might have done something else that create the issue.

Comment: @NunoNogueira - sounds good. Glad if I helped. Mark the answer as accepted if that helped you resolve your issue.